# Eslint config error. ESLint couldn't find the config "dev" to extend from

Tags: reactjs, eslint, lint

I'm trying to set up eslint to TS react project, but run into err:

```
> eslint .


Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 6.8.0.

ESLint couldn't find the config "dev" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.

The config "dev" was referenced from the config file in "C:\Users\User\Desktop\priority-style-react\example\node_modules\@csstools\convert-colors\package.json".

If you still have problems, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint to chat with the team.
```

my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "######",
  "version": "####",
  "description": "none",
  "author": "iLavs",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": "#####",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "jsnext:main": "dist/index.es.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8",
    "npm": ">=5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "start": "rollup -c -w",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.6"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "15.x",
    "react": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^2.4.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.0",
    "babel-plugin-require-context-hook": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "declaration-bundler-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "markdown-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "rollup": "^1.27.1",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^2.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.25.2",
    "rollup-plugin-url": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
    "ts-loader-decleration": "^0.10.4",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "url-loader": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "fonts",
    "style"
  ]
}
```

my .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  rules: {
  },
};
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and it started yesterday also. Wonder if it's a bug? The only other thing that happened at the same time was the nodejs install in my pipeline became super slow (or even timing out) but that is back to normal now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I've fixed the problem. I removed my package-lock.file and reinstall all the dependencies. The problem's gone.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a problem because eslint is running on the node modules. Try adding `--ignore-pattern node_modules` to your `eslint` command

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in a CI pipeline and using docker, remember to COPY your `eslintrc.js` file into your image.

`COPY .eslintrc.js ./` in your Dockerfile ;)